# How do you Upload a raw image using AJAX?

Tags: android, ajax, image, cordova

I am currently getting a base64 encoded image from a mobile device's camera using PhoneGap, I would like to upload the image to a server to then store.  Not sure what the right approach is?

As expected, if I try to include the base64 string as a parameter I get the Error 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you use POST the server accepting the POST will need to be capable of decoding the base64 parameter.  Luckily the PhoneGap API provides a better way to do this with [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer).

You need to get the file handle to the image instead of the base64 encoding.  Using the file handle resolves the issue of getting a JavaScript out of memory error.  This also removes any cross-site scripting issues since PhoneGap is using native code to perform the post instead of using the browser.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Chuck you are better off using the FileTransfer object.  Large Base64 strings will cause out of memory errors in your app.  Zac has a good tutorial on the subject:

http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET?